# ObservableCollection<IDictionary<String, String>> bind to Listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

```
    ObservableCollection<IDictionary<String, String>> ItemsSer = new ObservableCollection<IDictionary<String, String>>();

    foreach (XElement camposSer in document.Root.Elements("pm_venofer"))
    {
        Dictionary<String, String> Servicios = new Dictionary<String, String>();

            foreach (XElement columSer in document.Root.Element("columns").Elements("column"))
            {
                Servicios.Add(columSer.Value, camposSer.Element(columSer.Attribute("name").Value) != null ? camposSer.Element(columSer.Attribute("name").Value).Value : null);
            }
            ItemsSer.Add(Servicios);
        }
        listaServicios.ItemsSource = ItemsSer;
```

In ItemsSer, I have a collection of 20 dictionaries (each with 6 inputs).

What we want is show in 20 panels, each with 6 imputs of each object ItemSer

Comment: ObservableCollection<IDictionary<String, String>> ItemsSer = new ObservableCollection<IDictionary<String, String>>();

Comment: I forgot to put it above the foreach

Comment: c #, making an application for WP8